# Blurry image with see-through text on top using html and css like iOS 13 new UI

Tags: html, css, xcode, ios13

So basically the other day, I was messing around with Xcode.

I saw an Apple video explaining about UI and some new blur effects in IOS 13 so I tested it out and really liked it.

So what I achieved was an image with a blur effect and some text on top, but the text had a different blur than the image, so it was somehow see-tough.

Here is the result:

[image]

So basically I would like to achieve this using HTML and CSS but it looks quite difficult.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Thanks in advance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS, you can either use `opacity` property or use `rgba` colour values.
like so:

```html
<style>
div.background {
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/320/240) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* using the opacity property */
  opacity: 0.6;
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold; 
  /* Green background with 70% opacity */
  color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.7);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My computer isn't allowing me to see the image at the moment, but if you want to blur the background, you can use:

```
filter: blur(8px);
-webkit-filter: blur(8px);
```

etcetera, for each browser. Be sure to apply those styles to the image itself, and not the container.

You can check out the effect here: https://theexplorerblog.com/learning-base.php

Hope this helps.